# How can I remove a node from my galera cluster?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

Is there any better way of doing it,apart from setting 'wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://' for each node that I want to remove?

Comment: Might this help?  http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/autoeviction.html

Comment: But all the methods are based on some values,satisfying which the node gets removed.But what I am looking for is to remove the node manually,at any given point of time?

Answer (score 8):

I just did this.  Seems to have worked.  On the node you want to evict

Try

```
>show global status like 'wsrep%';
```

Copy paste the `wsrep_gcomm_uuid`

Go to another node and evict from there assuming the UUID = `1de97dad-f609-11e5-8a50-ce2e621b0c42`

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_provider_options="evs.evict=1de97dad-f609-11e5-8a50-ce2e621b0c42";
```

If the node is already shut down or non-responsive you can get the UUID from any other node from  `wsrep_evs_delayed`

Answer (score 1):

I see two choices here:

http://www.severalnines.com/blog/online-schema-upgrade-mysql-galera-cluster-using-rsu-method

(You aren't doing RSU, but that involves "removing a node".)